# Class not find, if the name is dynamic - PHP

Tags: php

I am using `PHP` with `Laravel`.

I have a method in the custom library:

```
use App\Models\ModelClassName;
.....
function import($class, $source){
    foreach ($source as $val){
        $model= new $class();
        $model->name = $val->name;
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

which I am calling in this way in the controller:

```
    $customLibrary = new Libraries\CustomLibrary();
    $this->import('ModelClassName', $arrayObjectsWithName);
```

I am getting this error:

> Class 'ModelClassName' not found

, but I have that class and I am using `use App\Models\ModelClassName;`.
If I hardcode the name of the class in the import method:
`$model = new ModelClassName();` instead `$model = new $class();`, it works fine.

Comment: did you include/require that file? are you using an autoloadeer?

Comment: That won't work. The namespace aliases are at compile time, not runtime, so when you're hitting the string 'ModelClassName' it's looking literally for that. Using `$this->import(ModelClassName::class, ...)` may work.

Comment: [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7745c28a6be5612149d63a93076830a713007da3)